# What iOS framework is needed for this particular audio manipulation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation, core-audio

Before I go sit down a read an entire book on CoreAudio, I wanted to know if it was the best Framework for me to study or if AVFoundation can do what I need. I want to be able to download a small portion of an MP3 located on a remote server, lets say 20 seconds of the file, preferable without downloading the entire file first then trimming it.

Then I want to layer 2 tracks of audio then bounce them as into one file.

Will I need to delve into CoreAudio or can AVFoundation so the trick? Advise is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downloading part of the file is up to you, but if you want to mix 2 or more audio files into one, AVFoundation is probably the easiest route to take, using `AVAssetExportSession` to do the exporting and `AVMutableAudioMix` to do the mix.. There is some example code for a simple editor floating around in the apple docs but cant seem to find it, if i do I will post the link..

Here is a method that actually does the mix, keep in mind that im adding video here as well, _audioTracks and _videoTracks are mutable arrays with AVAssets in them

```
-(void)createMix
{

    CGSize videoSize = [[_videoTracks objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = nil;
    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = nil;

    composition.naturalSize = videoSize;


    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];



    AVAsset *videoAsset=[_videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];
   CMTimeRange  timeRangeInAsset = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [videoAsset duration]);
        AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:timeRangeInAsset ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
        [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:timeRangeInAsset ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    NSMutableArray *trackMixArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(_audioTracks && _audioTracks.count>0)
    {
        for(AVAsset *audio in _audioTracks)
        {
          //     CMTimeRange  timeRangeInAsset = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [audio duration]);
           // AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[audio tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
            //[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:timeRangeInAsset ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


            NSInteger i;
            NSArray *tracksToDuck = [audio tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]; // before we add the commentary

            // Clip commentary duration to composition duration.
            CMTimeRange commentaryTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audio.duration);
            if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(CMTimeRangeGetEnd(commentaryTimeRange), >, [composition duration]))
                commentaryTimeRange.duration = CMTimeSubtract([composition duration], commentaryTimeRange.start);

            // Add the commentary track.
            AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
            [compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, commentaryTimeRange.duration) ofTrack:[[audio tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:commentaryTimeRange.start error:nil];



            CMTime rampDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 2); // half-second ramps
            for (i = 0; i < [tracksToDuck count]; i++) {
                AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:[tracksToDuck objectAtIndex:i]];
                [trackMix setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0.2 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(commentaryTimeRange.start, rampDuration), rampDuration)];
                [trackMix setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.2 toEndVolume:1.0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeRangeGetEnd(commentaryTimeRange), rampDuration)];
                [trackMixArray addObject:trackMix];

            }


        }
    }

     // audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray;

    if (videoComposition) {
        // Every videoComposition needs these properties to be set:
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30); // 30 fps
        videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize;
    }


    AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1280x720];
    session.videoComposition = videoComposition;
    session.audioMix = audioMix;

    NSUInteger count = 0;
    NSString *filePath;
    do {
        filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();

        NSString *numberString = count > 0 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%i", count] : @"";
        filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Output-%@.mp4", numberString]];
        count++;
    } while([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);      

    session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

     [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             NSLog(@"Exported");
             if(session.error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"had an error %@", session.error);
             }
             if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishExportingMovie:)])
             {
                 [delegate didFinishExportingMovie:filePath];
             }


     });
     }];



}
```

hope it helps..

Daniel

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel. When you say is up to me, do you mean that the entire file must be downloaded first before I can trim it?

Comment: @Wasim well it is possible to download a portion of it, but what i meant you have to figure out how many bytes you need, where the headers are (if there are any) etc..There are ways to do that in iOS but im pretty sure you need to have the whole file for that..

Comment: Many thanks for the code you've supplied, going to be a real help. So if the URL is the direct link to the MP3, would the headers have all the information regarding bytes etc? Couldn't I then just calculate the bytes needed based on that? Also what classes would I need to start looking at to get this done? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Wasim Well to get you started have a look at this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375309/audioqueue-how-to-find-out-playback-length-of-queued-data...however im not sure if you can get it to work with partial files..assuming you have the data used in the answer, then you should be able to use the code to calculate how many bytes you need

Comment: Thanks Daniel, big help! I'll take a look at the answer.