# AudioFileReadBytes and iPod assets

Tags: objective-c, ios, media-player, core-audio, ipod

I'm been accessing the raw sample audio data from iPod library audio assets, using the MediaPlayer framework, AVFoundation, and Core Audio. The iPod library URLs I know are only accessible from the audio APIs in iOS and I've been using the CMSampleBufferRef accessible from AVAssetTrack (copyNextBuffer). Now I've come to a need of accessing the audio data by way of random access and have hit a wall.

I'd like to be able to access the audio data using a byte offset, with AudioFileReadBytes or something similar. AudioFileReadBytes returns -4 (unimpErr) when attempting to use this for iPod tracks. Is random access using a byte offset actually possible? Is there another way to randomly access audio data using a timed offset (possibly using AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey when opening the asset), and translate a byte offset to a timed offset?

Comment: you basically want to read the bytes of data that correspond to some timecode? If so check out the answer i provide here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375309/audioqueue-how-to-find-out-playback-length-of-queued-data , you should be able to accomplish what you need

Comment: I actually want to reverse. Given a byte offset, I want to read a certain amount of bytes. If that means converting a byte offset to a time based representation then how is the possible without involving conversion, and respecting the disparate audio data formats found in an iPod library media collection.

I'm trying to avoid any overhead of conversion as the audio data needs to be accessed in near-realtime.

Comment: For advanced compressed audio formats, most byte offset are invalid for audio, as they reference a partial, thus broken packet.

Comment: This I'm aware of, I'm not attempting arbitrary random access :) The byte offset will be aligned to a packet or frame depending on the audio data format.